# Character repetition based on the numeric value in python in the string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in such a way that every character is followed by a numeric digit e.g. s3t2, w4, x1y2z4. I need to convert the string in such a way that every character will be repeated with the following numeric digit. e.g. for input s3t2 output should be ssstt, for input x1y2z4, the output will be xyyzzzz. Can you please help in Python to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `re` module for this task.

```
re.findall("([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)", 's3t2')
```

This will give you output like this,

```
[('s', '3'), ('t', '2')]
```

And then by using the basics of string you can get your expected string,

```
''.join([i[0] * int(i[1]) for i in r])
```

Final code:

```
import re
s = 's3t2'
r = re.findall("([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)", s)
print(''.join([i[0] * int(i[1]) for i in r]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the shortest expression, but working.

```
t = 'x1y2z4'  
res = ''.join([''.join([t[i] for j in range(int(t[i+1]))]) for i in range(len(t)) if i%2==0])
print(res)
>> 'xyyzzzz'
```